# Can we use IP addresses of multiple servers to the Azure CORS 'Allowed origins' rule?

Tags: azure, cors, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm having multiple subdomains,Can we use IP addresses of multiple servers to the Azure CORS 'Allowed origins' rule?

Comment: as per this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services#example--cors-rules-evaluation) yes!! you can use multiple origins,

Comment: @ManishTiwari I'm talking about servers ip like https : // 123.321.159.123,where my all websites are hosted,where all request come & goes of my multiple subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No!** we can not give IP address, it accepts domain name.
 [image]

For more information -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-cors-support

Answer (score 1):

CORS checks for domain name or ip in  originating headers . If you are running multiple websites/webapps  on same ip . You will need to allow add each domain or you can use regular expression with all valid origins or you can use allow all ( not recommended).

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

You can add ip and even  port to list of Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://10.10.50.50:2678"

It will not allow If you just add ip address and request comes from domain name.